# query doesn't work with multiple ranges

Tags: google-sheets

I have 3 cells that I run a query on.

```
| name | val | name |
|------+-----+------|
| Test |  1  | Test |
```

I want to return True if the value is greater than 1. The problem occurs when I try to have the cells separated.. I did a demo to show what I mean (sorry for my bad explaination)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nh_YZPtswmTxbvNktTdJtSNchDMkWJt6nVfnV8sKhP8/edit?usp=sharing

This works fine:

```
=if(QUERY(A2:F2;"select B where A like F";-1) > 1; True; False)
```

These doesn't work:

```
=if(QUERY(A2:B2,F2;"select B where A like F";-1) > 1; True; False)
=if(QUERY({A2:B2;F2};"select B where A like F";-1) > 1; True; False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

`=if(QUERY({A2:B2\F2};"select Col2 where Col1 like Col3";-1) > 1; True; False)`

Your first error is `{}`: to place columns next use slash `{Col\Col}`
The second error is using `ABC` notation. When using `{}` data is converted into array, so use `Col1, Col2...` for columns.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: I wanted to use multiple ranges in query. Unfortunately `\`` did not work for me. I had to do `{A2:A, C2:C}` to use range of A and C (without the first row) and then the naming of the columns was critical. So `Col1` and `Col2` worked. Thanks